# how to forward animation controller as the user drag in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

im trying to animate my screen (i have 3 animations tied to 1 controller) as the user drag the FAB from bottom center to center vertically.

here is my code:

```
GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
    widget.menuAnimationController
        .animateTo(fabPosition.normalize(targetPosition));        
      },
      onVerticalDragEnd: (_) {
        widget.menuAnimationController.animateTo(1);
      },
child: MyFAB();
) ;
```

the .normalize extension getter returns a value between 0 and 1 depending on the given val.

my issue is the `animate.To(val)` is setting the new value of `myAnimationController` and showing changes on the screen **the second i stop dragging** (without releasing my finger) **not as I drag** while the behaviour i need is **to animate as i drag** and complete from the current value `onVerticalDragEnd`.

how can achieve this ?

Comment: `widget.menuAnimationController.value = ...`

Comment: @pskink omg i don't believe it worked :D i remember that i tried to do so but got an error of animationController.value = .... can not be used as a setter... i checked now and i think i got that error while trying to set the value of an "Animation" instance not the AnimationController :P anyway thank you so much :))